# Satisfiability proofs

Tags: logic

∀x∃y (P(x, y) ^ y != c ) ^ ∀x∀y∀z (x = y or not P(x, z) or not P(y, z)

What's a predicate P and constant c that would show this is true on the naturals numbers. And what's the proof that it's not satisfiable on a finite, non-empty universe?

P1: ∀x(s(x) != 0)
P2: ∀x∃y(s(x) = s(y) implies  x = y)
P3: ∀x(x + 0 = x)
P4: ∀x∃y(x + s(y) = s(x + y))

What's the proof that ∀x∀y (x + y) = (y + x) is not a logical consequence of P1, P2, P3, P4?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what is motivating your question?

Comment: Voted to close: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be an exercise in mathematics.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap, well, this kind of problem is often used in introduction to logic courses in philosophy, in order to illustrate the concepts of satisfiability. My opinion is that there is an enormous region of topics in logic, where it is difficult to say whether it is mathematics or philosophy, and in general I find logic questions to be on-topic on this site. Even Frege complained that the philosophers thought he was doing mathematics and the mathematicians thought he was doing philosophy.

Comment: @JDH: I agree that there is ample room here for logic, and even mathematics. However, I don't think our aim here is to answer mathematics exercises unless motivated on philosophical grounds.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, interpret c as the number 0, and interpret P(x,y) as y = x+1. Since for every natural number x the number y=x+1 is not zero, the first clause holds in your desired statement. The second clause holds because if P(x,z) and P(y,z), then z=x+1=y+1, and so x=y. So the second clause also holds, and the statement is satisfied by this interpretation in the natural numbers.

The statement is not satisfiable in any finite domain, because the second part of the clause is exactly saying that the relation P is one-to-one, in the sense that there are never two different objects x and y both related to a single object z. And the first clause is saying that the relation P is not surjective, in the sense that no object x is related to the object c. If we had a model of the statements on a finite set, then we could define a function f(x)= some (any) y such that P(x,y) holds. This would be a one-to-one function on that finite domain, by the second clause. But any one-to-one function on a finite domain must be onto, by the pigeon-hole principle, and this will violate the first clause.  (The issue of non-empty domain is moot because the language has a constant symbol c, which must be interpreted in the domain, so the domain is nonempty).

Your last question is totally different and should have been asked as a separate question.
You can make a model of your theory by defining S(x)=x+1 on the natural numbers, but defining + by x+0=x, and x+y=x+1 if y is not 0. (That is, we redefine addition to be this weird thing that ignores y in x+y unless y is 0, and otherwise only adds 1 rather than adding y.) Now you get all your axioms being true, since P4 only says every x has *some* y for which it works, and you can take y=0 to satisfy P4. But x+y=y+x will not generally be true, for example 0+2 will be just 1, but 2+0 will be 2 on this interpretation.